# Can we change the structure of the feature-extraction layers of deep networks architectures?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I want to know if we can change the structure of the feature-extraction layers in the deep networks architectures, for example can we add more Rectified Linear Unit (ReLU) activation function or is it the same sequence that we should respect ?

Answer (score 1):

You can change whatever you like!

The benefits will depend on your data and what exactly you are comparing to. As you didn't say exactly what *sequence* you have as your starting point, I can't compare anything exactly, but provide a simple outline.

Generally, you follow the following recipe:

- **Input layer**: perform any reshaping or normalisation of your data
- **Multiplication layer**: either fully-connected layer, a convolutional layer or something else
- **Non-linearity**: `relu`, `tanh` - gives the network its power to fit non-linear functions
- **regularisation layer**: `batchnorm`, `dropout` - help models converge and prevent overfitting

This scheme is then repeated as many times as you feel is necessary.

---

Doing something like applying several ReLU layers, one after another, definitely doesn't make sense, as it would actually change anything! A ReLU simply filters out negative values, setting them to zero. Applying it a second time would therefore have no effect.